# Clarification about this proof about Dilworth's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Theorem 6.1. Let P be a partially ordered finite set. The minimum
number m of disjoint chains which together contain all elements
of P is equal to the maximum number M of elements in an
antichain of P.
Proof: (i) It is trivial that m ≥ M.
(ii) We use induction on |P|. If |P| = 0, there is nothing to
prove. Let C be a maximal chain in P. If every antichain in P\C
contains at most M − 1 elements, we are done. So assume that
{a1, . . . , aM} is an antichain in P\C. Now define S− := {x ∈ P :
∃i[x ≤ ai]}, and define S+ analogously. Since C is a maximal chain,
the largest element in C is not in S− and hence by the induction
hypothesis, the theorem holds for S−. Hence S− is the union of M
disjoint chains S
−
1 , . . . , S
−
M, where ai ∈ S
−
i . Suppose x ∈ S
−
i and
x > ai. Since there is aj with x ≤ aj , we would have ai < aj ,
a contradiction. This shows that ai is the maximal element of the
chain S
−
i , i = 1, . . . , m. We do the same for S+. By combining the
chains the theorem follows.
Could someone explain the proof in a simpler manner and
what is exactly meant by the term maximal chain in P ?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maximal chain is one that cannot be extended any more. That means any other element you add to a maximal chain will never result in a longer chain.
The above proof is by induction on the size of the poset $P$. The idea is to remove a maximal chain $C$ from $P$ to have a smaller poset. Then use the induction hypothesis.